# Is it a good idea to place Ajax requests into a separated routes group?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

As Laravel Doc says:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirects

> .... by using the global back helper function. Since this feature utilizes the session, make sure the route calling the back function is using the web middleware group...

I found myself in a situation where my application performs a redirect using back() in a Middleware.

And the unexpected result was to be redirected to a Ajax sub-request endpoint and not to the parent webpage. (e.g. to a json answer)

Since the preamble in the documentation I'm wondering if it's going to be a better practice to define ajax requests endpoints to another route group (not in web.php but in api.php ? or different custom-ajax.php?) to strip out from session history the ajax request and have the back function point to the parent page.

Comment: It will be better if you paste your code implementation so that other people can think out of the box of some better implementation. And also its a bit confusing why you'd want to redirect back if your request can be ajax too.

Comment: What I understand here is that when you call back() helper it redirect you to an ajax route ?

Comment: Example useCase (let's just assume that this is not weird, and focus on the purpose): Let's say I'm on a website page that performs subsequent in-page ajax requests to get json data. Then on browser address bar and I digit a new address that's managed by a a middleware that prevents from getting that urls and uses laravel helper back()" function. Result is that I'm redirected to the latest ajax request, displaying the json output.

Comment: Normally the back helper uses referrer header value (sets by the browser in your http request) to direct you back, that's mean performing ajax inside your page will not affect the referrer header, expect if your middleware modify it, Or maybe you are using an old browser.